# Acessar servidor php embutido do docker no Host

Tags: php, docker, webserver, slimframework

Bom pessoal to estudando docker aqui e junto com isso quero criar um servidor php (pelo seu servidor embutido) e ai então acessar esse servidor de minha máquina HOST.

Executei o seguinte comando:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v "D:\git\slim-saa:/home" -w "/home" my_opensuse_slim php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php
```

Apos executar esse comando o servidor roda normalmente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As portas e os volumes são mapeados normalmente (eu acho kk):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando vou na minha maquina e acesso o localhost:8080, não acesso nada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vocês tem ideia sobre o que de fiz errado?

Comment: Jhonatan, o [pt.so] possui uma estrutura de perguntas e respostas, que difere de um fórum. Na nossa estrutura, a solução do problema deve estar sempre presente na área de respostas e nunca na pergunta. Se encontrou por si só a solução, sinta-se a vontade para responder a própria pergunta. Isso não só é permitido como é altamente incentivado na nossa comunidade. Recomendo que leia o [tour] para entender melhor o funcionamento do site.

Comment: Feito @AndersonCarlosWoss Obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontrei o problema mas não a solução definitiva. Ocorreu que meu mapeamento contêiner-host estava certo, problemático mesmo estava a maneira que eu estava/estou utilizando o servidor web embutido do php. Instalei o php+apache normalmente na imagem e ao levantar o servidor web tudo funcionou.